# Rewrite URL to a more meaningful URL - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am pulling in some URLs from following SQL table with following columns:

- Name - Contains the Name of site
- URL - Contains the URL of site

I am then generating dynamic HyperLinks and attaching them to a gridview column:

```
protected void grdReport_Bnd(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[1].Visible = false;
        e.Row.Cells[2].Visible = false;


        string qry = e.Row.Cells[2].Text;   // Pulling the URL
        string username = (string)Session[Constants.AssociateID];  // Pulling associate ID frpm session.
        string qry1 = qry + "?ID=" + username;   // Passing the associate ID to the URL
        string txt = e.Row.Cells[1].Text.ToString();   // Pulling the text to display on hyperlink.

        HyperLink lnk = new HyperLink();
        lnk.Text = txt;
        lnk.NavigateUrl = qry1;
        lnk.Attributes.Add("Border", "0");
        lnk.Attributes.Add("Target", "_blank");
        e.Row.Cells[3].Controls.Add(lnk);
    }
}
```

Now I need to hide this resultant URL. For example the URL at the hyperlink may be: `http://1.20.40.40:8050/?ID=123456` which should be displayed as `http://mysite.com/ABC` where `abc` is the text from hyperlink and `mysite.com` is the site where this hyperlink is getting displayed.

I have seen various examples but could not understand them.

Comment: Are you sure to hide destination link? I would be suspicious about redirect...

Comment: I am creating something that would be published on intranet. I do not want to give away the actual URL of the destination to the users. For this reason I need to hide / replace / mask the URL.

Comment: Maybe the best practice involves IIS (or any other server) url mapping and masking/cloacking and not code tricks. In this way you can make use of current address but IIS will display masked URL.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, but can this be done through coding and not IIS URL mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured out that a simple rewrite won't work in this case. Hence, I have now added different pojects under one solution.